# How can a textarea display different content than shown in the console using Custom Component?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I have been playing with a `Custom Web Component` and have stumbled upon a curious effect I have not seen before and cannot solve the issue.

The web-component takes user clicks ( on either alpha chars, numbers or punctuation ) and appends to a textarea. This aspect works OK until manually adding content to the textarea via keyboard input. Once characters have been added in this manner what one observes in the textarea and what one can see when `inspecting` the textarea using the dev tools are different. Furthermore no input from the web-component input elements register within the displayed data in the textarea but DO register within the console view.

This has me puzzled so I hope the StackOverflow hive-mind can deduce what I cannot from this. The snippet should also exhibit this same behaviour. Any ideas?

A series of screenshots showing effect described:
[image: Input from web-component - OK]
All OK at this stage

[image: Input from keyboard]
All appears OK - sort of

[image: Discrepency obvious]
Cannot explain this discrepency

[image: What is going on?]
After clicking "input elements" - no visible display difference

---

A greatly simplified example still exhibits this behaviour with focus and display discrepency.

```js
class CharImp extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.attachShadow( { mode:'open',delegatesFocus:true } );
    };
    create(t,a,p){
        let el = document.createElement( t );
        for( let x in a ) if( a.hasOwnProperty( x ) ) el.setAttribute( x, a[ x ] );
        if( a.hasOwnProperty('text') ) el.innerText=a.text;
        p.appendChild( el );
        return el;
    };
    connectedCallback(){
        const rand=(a,b)=>Math.floor( Math.random() * ( b - a + 1 ) + a );
        let text=this.create('textarea',{cols:100,rows:10},this.shadowRoot)
        let bttn=this.create('input',{ type:'button', value:'Add Input' },this.shadowRoot)
            bttn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
                text.textContent += String.fromCharCode( rand(65,90) );
            })
    };
}
window.customElements.define( 'char-imp', CharImp );
```

```html
<char-imp></char-imp>
```

Essentially I am more interested in finding why input from the web-component "input elements" fails to register once manual input has happened.

Comment: sorry, too much code to comprehend. Trim it down to the bare essentials (and most likely you will fix your own bug this way)

Comment: Well - turns out I'm an idiot. I was modifying the `textContent` attribute of the textarea when I really should have been setting the value.

Comment: No, you are a discoverer. You discovered a place to hide HTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look at your code, only ran the Code Snippet

- I typed: abc
- then clicked the Letter button
- clicked: def

[image]

Looks like you are adding typed letters **not** like you add clicked letters

Clicked letters end up in **lightDOM** and are not *reflected* to shadowDOM
(because `<textarea>` does not have a `<slot>`)

The *Why* is in your code somewhere.

Comment: Now I looked at your code. You need to use the value property on textarea, not textcontent?